# MultipleDetailViews with navigation controllers on both sides of SplitViewController

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I need to show a list of categories on the left, and when a user selects a category, I need to show a list of items of the selected category on the right.  Then, if a user selects a list item on the right, I need to show the details of the selected item (again on the right).

So I am using Apple's sample MultipleDetailViews as a template, with a tableview on the left, and multiple detail viewcontrollers on the right. When a category is selected on the left, I create a navigation controller on the right and push a tableview controller to display the list of items in the category.  When an item is selected on the right, I push a new tableview controller to display the details of the item.  All this is working fine.

Now some of the categories on the left have sub-categories.  I could show the sub-categories on the right in a UITabBar, but I've been asked to display the sub-categories on the left.  So I need to push a new tableview controller on the left - which I have been able to do.

When I select a row in the new tableview on the left, I would like to create a new navigation controller on the right - just like I did for items in the main categories. I cannot get this to work and I know it is because the new tableview controller doesn't know anything about the DetailViewControllers.  But I can't figure out how to get this working.  Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Figured it out with help from another forum.  If anyone is interested, here's the solution:
[RWForums](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=40&p=1879#p1879)